# Automatically pause a playing sound only on certain slides in a PowerPoint slide show

Tags: vba, powerpoint, slideshow

I have a PowerPoint 2013 slide show with automatically advancing slides and background music. Some of the slides are videos and I would like the music to pause at such slides and automatically resume after. I could only find out how to make the music stop after a certain number of slides, but could not find out anything about pause/resume. Is this possible to do through the menus, or only with VBA?

Thanks a lot.
Iliya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't found any solution,
you can try some VBA, using "MCISendString", an external API function from winmm.dll.

One thing you should be careful is that there can't be any space character in 'fileToPlay' string.
You can automate playing and resuming the audio playing by using another function named OnSlideShowPageChange.

```
#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Function mciSendString Lib "winmm.dll" Alias _
    "mciSendStringA" (ByVal lpstrCommand As String, ByVal _
    lpstrReturnString As Any, ByVal uReturnLength As Long, ByVal hwndCallback As Long) As Long
#Else
    Declare Function mciSendString Lib "winmm.dll" Alias _
    "mciSendStringA" (ByVal lpstrCommand As String, ByVal _
    lpstrReturnString As Any, ByVal uReturnLength As Long, ByVal hwndCallback As Long) As Long

#End If

Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(SSW As SlideShowWindow)

    Dim fileToPlay As String
    Dim MCIAudio As Long

    fileToPlay = Chr(34) & ActivePresentation.Path & "\test.mp3" & Chr(34)

    Select Case SSW.View.CurrentShowPosition
        Case 1:
            'first, close the previous playing and open new and play
            MCIPlay = mciSendString("close MyAudio", Nothing, 0, 0)
            MCIAudio = mciSendString("open " & fileToPlay & " alias MyAudio", Nothing, 0, 0)
            MCIAudio = mciSendString("play MyAudio", Nothing, 0, 0)
        Case 2:
            MCIAudio = mciSendString("pause MyAudio", Nothing, 0, 0)
        Case 3:
            MCIAudio = mciSendString("resume MyAudio", Nothing, 0, 0)
        Case 4:
            MCIAudio = mciSendString("stop MyAudio", Nothing, 0, 0)
    End Select
End Sub

Sub OnSlideShowTerminate()
    Dim MCIAudio As Long

    MCIAudio = mciSendString("stop MyAudio", Nothing, 0, 0)
    MCIAudio = mciSendString("close MyAudio", Nothing, 0, 0)
End Sub
```

In this example,
On Slide 1, starts playing.
On Slide 2, pauses Playing.
On Slide 3, resumes Playing.
On Slide 4, stops playing.
When the slide show ends, stops playing.

(You know, OnSlideShowPageChange sometimes fails to initiate.
If then, just insert any Active-X control on the first slide, 
which is a known workaround.)

Other MCISendString commands can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710815.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can view this [Link](http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/powerpoint/start-pause-and-resume-a-sound-file-in-a-powerpoint-2007-presentation/) for more answers to your question.

You should be able to do this without code. Power Point > Transitions Tab > Sounds: [Stop Previous Sound].

[image: Explanation Image]

Comment: I would like to pause the sound only on a specific slide, after which it resumes. And all should be automatic. I can't figure out how to do this with the proposed approach.